Theorems for interchanging limit and conditionally convergent integral
I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{s \to \infty}  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}x^{\frac{1}{s}} dx =  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ by exchanging the limit and the integral.
I'm aware of the dominated convergeance theorem, however I'm under the impression that the integral is only conditionally convergent, meaning any function that dominates the integrands absolute value wouldn't be integrable. What other theorems are applicable to bring the limit inside the integral?

here show that for $s >2$ say and $\epsilon>0$ there is $N(\epsilon)$ st $M>N>N(\epsilon)$ implies $|\int_N^M\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1-1/s}}dx| < \epsilon$ (from the second mean value theorem for integrals using that $1/x^{1-1/s} \le N^{-1/2}, x \ge N$ and $|\int_N^M \sin x| \le 2$) and then find $s(\epsilon)$ st $|\int_0^{N(\epsilon)}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}(x^{\frac{1}{s}}-1) dx| < \epsilon, s >s(\epsilon)$ which follows by dominated convergence since now $N(\epsilon)$ is fixed and putting it together you are done
